# How to output successive letters in C

Tags: c

Here is the homework question I am working on:

Declare a character variable letterStart. Write a statement to read a letter from the user into letterStart, followed by statements that output that letter and the next letter in the alphabet. End with a newline. Hint: A letter is stored as its ASCII number, so adding 1 yields the next letter. Sample output assuming the user enters 'd': de

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   char letterStart;

   scanf("%c", letterStart);

   printf("%c", letterStart);
   printf("%c", letterStart + 1);

   return 0;
}
```

Your output = (unknown character)

while the homework compiler wants to test 'a', so that the output is ab.

Any tips?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `&` symbol at

```
scanf("%c", letterStart);
```

Make it :-

```
scanf("%c", &letterStart);
```

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   char letterStart;

   scanf("%c", &letterStart);

   printf("%c", letterStart);
   printf("%c", letterStart + 1);

   return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
a
ab
```

Comment: You will probably want to add a few checks like `if (('a' <= letterStart && letterStart < 'z') || ('A' <= letterStart && letterStart < 'Z') {..}`

Answer (score 2):

Turn on compiler warnings:

```
$ gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:7:12: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    scanf("%c", letterStart);
            ^
main.c:7:4: warning: ‘letterStart’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    scanf("%c", letterStart);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And there you see the problem. Change to `scanf("%c", &letterStart);`